# How can I hide my AWS S3 access key and secret in C++?

Tags: c++, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS S3 in my C++ app to upload and download files. I've included the access key and secret in my code but I'm worried someone could read them from the binary. Is there any standard technique for obfuscating them?

Update: I'm not running this app on a PC, it's actually on an embedded device so I'm not worried about users reading the key and secret from a file or RAM (accessing the device is a lot harder). What I'm worried about is someone binwalking our update file and pulling the key and secret from the binary.

Comment: If I undertood correctly the question (and aswers given so far) the point is that a key in code could be read somehow. It does not mean that one could know where the actual key is but one could know where static data are and use this data as a base for a brute force attack (by trying e.g. all sequences of 4 chars, then of 5 and so on present in the static data).

Comment: This is a hard question to answer. I think it is not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve, and the answer (as it usually is with security) is probably "you're doing it wrong". As a rule of thumb, you can't keep anything secret from a user on their own pc. Have you considered asking over at http://security.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Storing a secret in computer is not an easy task. One thing you could do is encrypt the key using a password and store the encrypted data in a file. Then when user enters a password you can decrypt the encrypted data using the password and retrieve the key - which you can use.

But this approach will not work for scenarios where the software needs to run without user intervention.

Comment: Would not be better embed the encrypted data inside the code?

Comment: @marom: It is difficult for me to say, I think it depends on the situation. If the key is stored encrypted, where the encrypted data is stored, should not be too important.

Answer (score 0):

It is better not keeping keys in code. Input when needed.

If kept in code, do not keep the key in simple string. Keep it in some pattern, and generate the key by some algorithm when needed.

Comment: But then I'd have to give the AWS key and secret to the customer which defeats the point of hiding it.